# How to add fonts using tFPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, fpdf

I try to create pdf file using tFPDF with custom font. 
I put arial font inside font/unifont folder.
I use this code to create pdf file:

```
$pdf->AddFont('arialbd','','arialbd.ttf',true);

$pdf->SetFont('arialbd','',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,6, 'OÜ Kersti Võlu Koolituskeskus', 0, 1);

$pdf->SetFont('arialbd','',10);
$pdf->Cell(40,12,'REGISTREERIMISLEHT', 0, 1);

$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

It works well on localhost, but when I uploaded this file on server, it shows me an error: 
**Warning: fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\koolitus\wp-content\plugins\koolitus\fpdf/font/unifont/arialbd.ttf)** 
I see that library tries to load a font from my localhost, but I don't even set a path, just use font name 
How to add fonts properly?

Comment: Most likely a problem with your Wordpress configuration. Are you using the same database locally as on your server? That would be one place to see where your local setup is coming through. You have to set the proper path to the app directory in your config.

Comment: I use different databases. On localhost I use database called 'kvkoolitus' and on a server database name is ''d11194sd118225". I have  defined constant - define('PDF_PATH', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'fpdf/pdf.php'); This file generates pdf. In this file I use include_once('tfpdf.php'); to include tfpdf library. How to fix path?

Comment: You might check the URL settings: https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen

Comment: I have there right path: http://uus.kvkoolitus.ee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete all *.php and *.dat files in font/unifont folder except **ttfonts.php**. 
All this files will be re-created (with right path).

Comment: this saved me!! How did you come up with this? I couldn't find anything about this in readme or documentation !

Answer (score 1):

Another option: open every `mtx.php` file.

Replace the line (absolute path):

```
$ttffile='D:\xampp8\htdocs\test\include\tfpdf/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf';
```

With (relative path):

```
$ttffile='include/tfpdf/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf';
```