# tPDF error after reuploading ttf "Undefined font: dejavu"

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf

I am using the [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) package

```
$pdf=new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 12);
```

and it used to work. I had to reupload the font folder and since then I get the error message

> FPDF error: Undefined font: dejavu

but the file `DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf` is definitely in the fonts folder. I even changed the mod to `777` because I thought maybe access rights are the problem, but it is still not working. What else could cause this error?

---

[image]

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513082/how-to-add-fonts-using-tfpdf/38520012#38520012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay I just found the solution sorry for the post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38520012/2311074

> Delete all *.php and *.dat files in font/unifont folder except
>   ttfonts.php. All this files will be re-created (with right path).

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought it was Composer related, this would never crossed my mind. I was already going nuts over this, thanks once again.